# New dyes in RoS?

Tags: diablo-iii

Basically it's just what the title asks: Are there any new dyes introduced with the new expansion Reaper of Souls? And if there are some: How do I get them? Are they Act V only or are they only available in one of the new game modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No new dyes were added to the [game guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dye/) which was recently updated to include ROS items and mechanics.  Unless there are any Easter eggs, it would appear no new dyes were added.

Comment: I don't think the game guide is up to date yet, either that or [Ring of Royal Grandeur](http://diablo.blizzpro.com/2014/02/13/ars-arcanum-ring-royal-grandeur/) isn't in RoS :(

Comment: Could also be that that ring didn't make it to release.  Has it been seen in the wild?

Comment: The ring is definitely dropping I've seen 3-4 now in clan chat